# Asset file permissions issue hyperlane

Tags: templating, image, volumes

I am having trouble setting up image volumes correctly in Hyperlane.
My best guess is that is has something to do with permissions but I have not been able to find a solution.

This is how I have set up the image volume like instructed in [Hyperlane's documentation](https://docs.hyperlane.co/craft3/asset-sources/)
[image]

However when I am uploading images it doesn't show in the templates, and when opening the url path I get a 404.
You can see a page where I have uploaded an image here https://dev-craft3-f59ef5d673d0.hyperlane.co/work/nausea and when I right-click and open the image in a new tab I get a 404 https://dev-craft3-f59ef5d673d0.hyperlane.co/uploads/images/work/nausea.jpg

The template to get the image looks like this

```
  {% set image = entry.featuredImage.one() %}
  {% if image %}
  <div class="image-box">
    <figure>
      <img
      src="{{ image.getUrl() }}"
      alt="{{ entry.title }}">
    </figure>
  </div>
  {% endif %}
```

…and the field is set up like this
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Craft, assets are always "absolute" paths to the webroot, not relative to the URL (although you can make it like that).

So in your example, `@AssetPublicPath/images` is going to be replaced with `https://dev-craft3-f59ef5d673d0.hyperlane.co/uploads/images`.

If you want something to go into a subfolder, in this case `work`, you'd need to either specify that as another Craft Volume or specify that in the `featuredImage` [asset field](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/assets-fields.html#settings).

Looks like have "restrict uploads to a single folder" checked but there's nothing set in that field so Craft is getting confused as to where to put things.